# How do I Parse the Result of a JS Function to SVG Object?

Tags: javascript, parsing, svg, call, geometry

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
<![CDATA[
function setCoordinates(evt) {
var centerX = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
var centerY = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);      
evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"cx",centerX);
evt.target.setAttributeNS(null,"cy",centerY);
}
]]>
</script>
```

That's my function.
I'm really stuck on how to parse (not sure if that's the right word) the result to the attributes in a circle.

Let's say my circle is the following:

```
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red" />
```

What is the Javascript required to call the function and thus parse the attribute values to the circle?

Comment: What your after isn't clear. And it's also not clear what you current code is doing instead. What are you after?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Ww5/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want an event to be involved. You probably want something like

```
function setCoordinates(circle) {
  var centerX = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  var centerY = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);      
  circle.setAttribute("cx",centerX);
  circle.setAttribute("cy",centerY);
}
```

(`setAttributeNS()` is not needed if you're using the `null` namespace anyway.)

If you give your circle an ID, like

```
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="red" id="myCircle"/>
```

then you can change the coordinates with code like

```
setCoordinates(document.getElementById("myCircle"));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really clear and informative answer. Just what I was wanting :D